# About the use of quotation in sed problem

Tags: bash

Well. Thanks for all your kindly help. I have learn from your that, to use a variable in sed we have to use " " instead of ' '. However, in my case , before i use ' ' and without variable, it works well. After using  " " and variable ($title, $web, $desc) it doesn't functioning anymore, what is the reason?? thanks.

Before

```
sed -i '0,/<item pop="N">/ { s/<item pop="N">/<item pop="N">\n <title>test1<\/title>\n <guid>test2<\/guid>\n <link>test3<\/link>\n <description><![CDATA[<p>test4<\/p>]]><\/description>\n <\/item>\n<item pop="N">/ }' /var/www/html/INFOSEC/english/rss/test.xml
```

After

```
sed -i "0,/<item pop="N">/ { s/<item pop="N">/<item pop="N">\n <title>News: $title<\/title>\n <guid>$web<\/guid>\n <link>$web<\/link>\n <description><![CDATA[<p>$desc<\/p>]]><\/description>\n <\/item>\n<item pop="N">/ }" /var/www/html/INFOSEC/english/rss/test.xml
```

I have run it separately instead of the whole script
it turn out the error -bash: ![CDATA[: event not found, actually i should not run it alone as i need to input something in the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `"` inside the string. These characters need to be escaped.

Also, it's likely that your shell escapes the `\` characters inside `""`, and not inside `''`. You have at least two solutions:

Either keep everything inside `""` but replace `\` with `\\`, and `"`s with `\"`:

```
 sed -i "0,/<item pop=\"N\">/ { s/<item pop=\"N\">/<item pop=\"N\">\\n <title>News: $title<...
```

Or mix the two; when you need to insert a variable, exit `'`, enter your variable inside `""`, and re-enter `'`:

```
 sed -i '0,/<item pop="N">/ { s/<item pop="N">/<item pop="N">\n <title>News: '"$title"'<...
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch them up. As long as the quoted sections are contiguous, bash will consider them one string.

```
sed -i '0,/<item pop="N">/ { s/<item pop="N">/<item pop="N">\n <title>News: '"$title"'<\/title>\n <guid>'"$web"'<\/guid>\n <link>'"$web"'<\/link>\n <description><![CDATA[<p>'"$desc"'<\/p>]]><\/description>\n <\/item>\n<item pop="N">/ }' /var/www/html/INFOSEC/english/rss/test.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash [history expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) will trigger when the shell sees `!` inside double quotes. This is why the "event not found" error message appears. From the manual:

> Only ‘\’ and ‘'’ may be used to escape the history expansion character.

You could do this:

```
sed_script='0,/<item pop="N">/ { s/<item pop="N">/<item pop="N">\n <title>News: %s<\/title>\n <guid>%s<\/guid>\n <link>%s<\/link>\n <description><![CDATA[<p>%s<\/p>]]><\/description>\n <\/item>\n<item pop="N">/ }'
sed -i "$(printf "$sed_script" "$title" "$web" "$web" "$desc")" /var/www/html/INFOSEC/english/rss/test.xml
```

Or (I'm not a sed expert), does this work the same? It is more readable

```
sed_script='/<item pop="N">/ a \
<title>News: %s</title> \
<guid>%s</guid>\n <link>%s</link> \
<description><![CDATA[<p>%s</p>]]></description> \
</item> \
<item pop="N">'
sed -i "$(printf "$sed_script" "$title" "$web" "$web" "$desc")" /var/www/html/INFOSEC/english/rss/test.xml
```